# Converse of Lagrange's Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

I want to know partial converse of Lagrange's theorem is true upto how much ?

We know that it holds only in case of cyclic groups.

Also if a group has order $p^m\times n;\gcd(m,n)=1$ then it has a subgroup of order $p^i;1\leq i\leq m$ by sylow's theorem

But can we say something about existence of a subgroup of order $pm$?Is this a good research topic or we already have something in this direction

Comment: Look up Sylow's theorems.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to ask about subgroups of order $pn$? And assume that $\gcd(p,n)=1$?

Comment: if $gcd(p,n)=1$?

Comment: For abelian groups this [has been discussed previously](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/910426/every-abelian-group-is-a-converse-lagrange-theorem-group).  It is not generally true, even if we assume $n$ is a prime distinct from $p$.  E.g. [Why $A_5$ has no subgroup of order $15$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/910426/every-abelian-group-is-a-converse-lagrange-theorem-group)

Comment: Do you know the subgroups of $A_4$?